# Dropdown not binding data fetch from two tables

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

I have a dropdown list, and that list fetch it from database.But it's not binding to the dropdownlist.

> > In here the condition is 1 book have many BookTypes.

Here i have paste the codings.

```
  public List<BookModel> GetBooks(string bookId)
    {


            DatabaseProviderFactory factory = new DatabaseProviderFactory();
            Database db = factory.Create("DefaultConString");
            con.Open();

            String query = @"Select B.BookName,B.Author,BT.BookType
                             FROM VW_Book B
                             INNER JOIN VW_BookType BT
                             ON B.BookId = BT.BookId
                             WHERE BookId =: BookId";


           cmd = db.GetSqlStringCommand(query);
           db.AddInParameter(cmd, "BookId", DbType.String,bookId);

           var ds = db.ExecuteDataSet(cmd);

           var da = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(d => new StaffModel {
               bookname= d.Field<string>("BookName"), //From Book table
               authorname = d.Field<string>("AuthorName"), //From Book table
               booktype = d.Field<string>("BookType"); // From BookType table
           });
           var lst = da.ToList();
           return lst;

      }
```

### My Controller

```
  [HttpPost]
    public string GetBookDetails(string bookId)
    {

           BookBusiness bk = new BookBusiness();
            List<BookModel> _book = bk.GetBookDetails("50000").ToList();
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_book); //

    }
```

### My Model

```
    Public class BookModel
{
public string BookId {get;set;}
public string BookName {get;set;}
public string BookType {get;set;}
}
```

### Ajax Call

```
        $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetBookDetails", "Books")',
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        data: JSON.stringify({ BookId: BookId}),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (_book) {
            debugger;
            $('#bookdropdown').empty();

            $.each(_book, function () {
                $("#bookdropdown").append(
                    $('<option/>', {
                        value: this,
                        html: this
                    })
                );
            });
        }
    });
```

But the issue here i face is that Data not bind to the dropdownlist.
data comes like [{"HarryPotter"}] like json format.

Comment: what is the response your ajax call receiving from the `GetBookDetails` call ? Can you do a `console.log(_book)` inside the success event and paste the stringified version in your question ?

Comment: And your `GetBookDetails` method returns  a string ? You should return an array of items and loop through that in your client side code.

Comment: Something is amiss (in addition to what @Shyju has brought up). The `GetBooks` method signature returns a `List<BookModel>`, however, the implementation actually returns a `List<StaffModel >`. Further, the ajax query is looking for a BookId, but the `GetBooks` method doesn't even set a BookId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ajax method expects json, so you need to change the controller method to

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetBookDetails(string bookId)
{
    BookBusiness bk = new BookBusiness();
    List<BookModel> _book = bk.GetBookDetails("50000").ToList();
    return Json(_book);
}
```

However its unclear which of the properties of `BookModel` you want in the view. Only 2 properties need to be returned, one for assigning to the options `value` attribute, and one for the options display text (and if they are the same, then only one property needs to be returned). There is no point sending additional data across the wire which is never used so assuming you want the `BookId` and `BookName` properties, the the controller method would be

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetBookDetails(string bookId)
{
    BookBusiness bk = new BookBusiness();
    var books = bk.GetBookDetails("50000").Select(b => new
    {
        value = b.BookId,
        text = b.BookName  
    };
    return Json(books);
}
```

Then your script will be

```
var dropdown = $("#bookdropdown"); // cache it
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("GetBookDetails", "Books")',
    type: "POST",
    data: { BookId: BookId }, // no need to stringify and add contnetType
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (books) {
        debugger;
        dropdown.empty();
        $.each(books, function(index, item) {
            dropdown.append($('<option><option/>').val(item.value).text(item.text));
        });
    }
});
```

Side note. The code you have shown will not compile. Your `GetBooks()` method returns `List<BookModel>` but its code is creating `List<StaffModel>`. In addition the controller is calling a method named `GetBookDetails()`, not `GetBooks()` so I assume you have shown the wrong code. In addition you pass a parameter `bookId` to the controller but never use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
$.each( _book, function( i, val ) {
 $("#bookdropdown").append(
                    $('<option/>', {
                        value: val ,
                        text: val 
                    });

});
```